# Drilldown not working in Siebel

Tags: siebel

The "Type" field is configured with a drill down object. And i checked the responsibilities associated with the view to which i have to drill down.
I possess all the responsibilities associated with the view.
I also checked if the View was active and found it to be active in Tools.

Still i dont have the hyperlink in the values of that column in my client.

The "Type" filed is part of "Account Activity List Applet".
And the view that i have to drill down is "Activity Detail Summary View".

Comment: It may be obvious, but have you compiled your changes into SRF file? There is vanilla drilldown configured on this field. Can you try and test it with vanilla SRF? What is your Siebel version?

Comment: I am using Siebel 8.1

Comment: What about my other questions? Can you list step-by-step what you have done so far? The more information you provide the more likely somebody finds out what's wrong with your configuration.

Comment: The problem is that the drill down is working fine in the local environment(Thick Client) but the hyperlink is not available in the same field in the Production Environment.

Comment: Once again: have you compiled your changes into SRF file placed on production environment?

Comment: So i took a recently compiled SRF of the Production Environment and copied it into the Local Tools. Still i find the hyperlink available in the local environment and not in the Production Environemtn

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48539/discussion-between-dixon-and-yaroslav-shabalin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After duscussion in chat appeared that when server SRF is copied to dedicated client (Client > Objects> ENU > siebel_sia.srf) the drilldown is missing. But after compilation drilldown reappears. So the issue is definitely in server SRF file. To update configuration you have to copy updated SRF file to the appropriate directory on the server and restart application. Also there is method that doesn't need application server restart, see this [link](http://siebelunleashed.com/zero-downtime-siebel-srf-migration/) for details.